# Craft strips out parenthesis in file names.

Tags: assets

Is there any way to allow () in asset file names (ex. file(1).txt)? Craft strips it out when it saves. The only way I've found is to change it via ftp and update asset indexes.

I've set convertFilenamesToAscii => false but that didn't help.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, but I'd recommend from personal experience staying with sanitized, non-utf8 filenames. UTF8 filesystem is a slippery slope to go down even if your server permits it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see a way... uploads ultimately get run through [FileHelper::sanitizeFileName()](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/helpers/FileHelper.php#L124), which has a hard-coded list of disallowed characters in a file name (including parenthesis).

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/helpers/FileHelper.php#L128-L166